# How to fix this error :pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new here and learning about topics of dynamic memory and linked list. And here is the problem that I have encountered.

```
void deletenode(Node*& head){
Node* temp = new Node;
temp = head; // I would like to create a new pointer to store the value of head node.
head=head->next; // and here I want to change the head node to the next one as I am going to delete it right after.

delete temp; // after I used the temp pointer to store the address of (the old) head, I would like to delete it.
}
```

But I still got the error message from it.

```
malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

In my prior knowledge of memory leak, if we do not delete the memory allocated by the new operator would cause memory leak as there will be so many garbage pointer. But why this problem still happened in my code as it seems like I have already deleted (or deallocated) the `temp`  pointer. I really could not figure out what problem I have made as I have just learnt this topic and I may still have so many misconceptions about this topic.

UPDATED:
Thanks for everyone's help. The problem has been solved. I just changed `Node* temp = new Node;` to `Node* temp=head;` And It works. Thank you so much for all of your advice!

Comment: The code begins by allocating a new node and storing its address in `temp`. Then it assigns the value of `head` to `temp`, throwing away the address of the new node. Then it fiddles with the node pointed to by `head`, and then it deletes the node pointed to by `head`. The complaint seems to be about that last line. Where did `head` come from? (In general, code that's simply removing a node doesn't need to allocate another node)

Comment: I am sorry but I still have some confusion. Let me give an example to make it clearer. For example, we assume the linked list look like this ```1->2->3->4```. And there will always be a ```head``` node pointing to the first node of the linked list. So, I would like to implement the function ```deletenode(head)``` to delete the first (or head) node of the linked list which is 1. And then make the ```head```node pointing to 2. Therefore, If I do not allocate a new pointer to save the original head node (which mean 1), I may not be able to delete ```1``` without deleting the whole ```head```(?) .

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory for `temp`. Doing `Node* temp = head` is enough to set `temp` equal to the first element.

Comment: To conclude, I do not aim to delete the ```head``` pointer. I just want to change the  ```head``` pointing to 2 from 1 and I do not need the 1 anymore. So, does that mean I just have to type ```head=head->next```. Then it will help me to change the head node from 1 to 2 and 1 will be deallocated automatically? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: `1` isn't deallocated automatically. It's only deallocated when you do `delete temp`. The memory for the list was already allocated before the function was called.

Comment: The other issue is that `head = head->next` doesn't change the original `head` pointer because it's a copy of the original `head` pointer. You need to change the function signature to `void deletenode(Node*& head)`.

Comment: So how should i do to delete ```1```  without deleting the ```head```node.

Comment: I am sorry! I actually put the ```&``` pass by ref in the header of the function but I forget to add it when I type the code here. I will edit it right away. But although I am passing value by reference, but still not working.

Comment: The code you have is fine except you need to replace `Node* temp = new Node()` with `Node* temp = head`.

Comment: Show the actual code instead of adding fragments in the comments. Was the head node created with `new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node* temp = new Node;
```

This creates a new object in dynamic scope, and sets `temp` to point to it.

At this point, you can go ahead and `delete` this object if you wish, and everything will work out at the end. But instead you do this:

```
temp = head;
```

This then immediately replaces the `temp` pointer, and it now points to some other mysterious object, that was passed into this function, that's referenced by this `head` pointer. If that object was also `new`ed at some point, it can certainly be `delete`d, but even if that's the case this will result in a memory leak, since nothing else points to the original `new`ed object, and it cannot be deleted.

```
 delete temp;
```

Well, this is now pointing to whatever `head` was pointing. If `head` was pointing to something that was `new`ed, it can be `delete`d here, otherwise this is undefined behavior, and a crash. And in all cases, the original `new` was leaked.